# My code is not working properly

Tags: javascript

The code is set to on the start slide forward and after 500 its suppose slide back. Well the code does slide forward but the code does not slide back after the 500. The code is not written properly as it should slide back. Here is the code JSFiddle:

```
$("#slideout").animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"}, function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#slideout").animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500})
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdvUQ/2/

If anybody can fix it up so that the code can slide back would be awesome.

Comment: I believe the problem is your excessive use of this strange '$' symbol. I am not sure what that thing is, but everywhere it goes on stack overflow, trouble follows.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with the animate arguments

```
$("#slideout").animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"}, function ()...
```

should be

```
$("#slideout").animate({right:'0px' , queue: false, duration: "slow"}, function ()...
```

You'll need to remove the closing/opening curly braces.